# pi 3 won't connect to the internet through an Ethernet cable

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, internet

Overnight I left my pi on so it could keep up the website I am hosting but come day my pi was not connecting to the internet so as I had setup a static ip (router side) I decided to delete the raspberry pi off the device list on the bt hub so it would go back to dynamic and it still won't connect to the internet I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: Raspbian Jessie isn't supported anymore. You should use Raspbian Buster now.

Comment: sorry i assumed that it is Jessie it is actually raspbian stretch

Comment: Can you try a ping 8.8.8.8 from the Pi and let us know the result? Also please run ifconfig from the Pi and pop the result here as well.  The first will test if it’s a name resolution or connection issue and the second will show if you have an IP address.

Comment: eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.206  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::8d14:75eb:ea68:da86  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:75:12:e4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 40  bytes 4398 (4.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ping -c 5 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.1.206 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4140ms
pipe 3